# Reading the markings on a reed switch

Tags: identification, reed-switch

I have the following reed switch.

[image]

The markings are:
170-842
N/O3

I'm not entirely sure what they may mean. It is used in a DC application to power a 24V, 6A DC motor, but that is all I know about it at this moment. Please let me know if more pictures are required.

Comment: The numbers may not mean anything; just like Farnell or RS part numbers are meaningless. What are you hoping to gain from understanding the numbers?

Comment: I am wondering whether they provide any insight into their electrical characteristics, or (even better) what exact part it is. But the knowledge that these numbers may be meaningless is also helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be from Farnell, with the part number given [170-842](https://uk.farnell.com/multicomp/n-03/proximity-switch-3a/dp/170842),
and is still available if you're looking for a replacement.

It's a normally-open reed switch, with these main characteristics:
[image]

<sup>From [data sheet](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/3179127.pdf)</sup>